# How to get ASP.NET MVC ModelState.IsValid() to pick up on changes i made to the model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got a auto-generated Create action in my controller, I've changed things a little, I have to modify the submitted model before I call ModelState.IsValid().

But the IsValid() is still saying its failed, I think this is because it goes off the received parameter, and ignores the changes I've made? How can I get it to validate after I've changed things?

Thanks

Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
        [CaptchaValidator]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Register(User user, bool captchaValid)
        {
            user.prepareUserForCreation();
            if (ModelState.IsValid && captchaValid)
            {
                db.Users.Add(user);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewData["captchaValidationMessage"] = captchaValid ? "" : "Your words didn't match, please try again";

            return View(user);
        }
```

Prepare method:

```
public void prepareUserForCreation()
        {
            this.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            this.LastSeen = DateTime.Now; //TODO remove this
            this.IsActivated = true; //TODO remove this
        SecurityHelper.HashPassword(this);
        }
```

Basically its saying password is null.

Comment: I suspect that your problems come from the fact that you are passing your domain entities to your views instead of using view models. Your domain entities are not adapted for the views and that's the reason why you should use a view model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `ModelState.Clear();` before you use prepare method and then call `TryValidateModel(user)` to validate it

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `ModelState.IsValid`, try using `TryValidateModel(user)`.  I believe this will manually perform the validation of the model after you've prepared it.